# Providing external arguments to Maven pom and replace same in application.properties file

Tags: maven, junit, testng, pom.xml

I am working on testNg project where I need to provide external arguments to the pom.xml which should get replaced in application.properties file which further will be used in my project.
Could anyone list out the steps and plugins i need to use.

Comment: Is the `application.properties` already a filtered resource? Then you can provide the parameters with `-Dparameter=value`.

Comment: It is disable by default

Comment: What is disabled?

Comment: What is the problem with making it filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I have added a profile in pom.xml and configuration for property substitution.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <properties>
                <url>https://www.bing.com</url>
                <search>bitcoin</search>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

<build>
   <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/runtime.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

runtime.properties

```
url=${url}
search=${search}
```

To Run the test:

```
mvn test -Pprofile1 -Durl=https://www.google.com -Dsearch=Blockchain
```

The value of url and search variable will be replaced in runtime.properties file by the value given in arguments of the above command .

```
    -Durl=https://www.google.com and
    -Dsearch=Blockchain
```

Comment: It worked for me with changing the "url=${url}" to  "url=@url@". Thanks!